# Toggle "show hidden files and folders with Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, directory, hidden

I have been trying to create a line item within a .bat or .ps script that toggles the "Show hidden files/folders" option ON. I am having no luck so far. I have tried using the `get-childitem` command in various flavors and it's not working for me. What am I missing?  Is this even something that can be done?

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Are you trying to display hidden files/folders in CMD or PowerShell, or toggle the Show hidden files/folders option of Explorer? If the latter, I recommend investigating a registry edit. I'm not sure there is a CLI command to change options of Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working from Ash's [fine script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67510876/toggle-show-hidden-files-and-folders-with-powershell/67524692#67524692),here's a slight enhancement.
This allows a third option of no parameter which will just toggles the current setting.

```
function Show-HiddenFiles {
 
   Param (
          [Parameter(Mandatory = $False,Position=0)]
            [String] $Setting
   )

   # Define the path to the registry key that contains the 
   # registry value/subkey
   $Path = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" +
           "\Explorer\Advanced"

   #No argument toggle setting..
   If ($Args.Count -eq 0) {

     $GIPArgs = @{Path = $Path
                  Name = "Hidden"}

     If ((Get-ItemProperty @GIPArgs ).Hidden -eq 1) {
       $Value = 2
     }
     Else {$Value = 1}   
   }
   Else {
   # Set a variable with the value we want to set on the 
   # registry value/subkey.
     If ($Setting -eq "On" ) { $Value = 1 }
     Else                    { $Value = 2 }
   }
   
   # Set the registry value/subkey.
   Set-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name Hidden -Value $Value

   # Refresh open Explorer windows.
   # You will need to refresh the window if you have none 
   # currently open.
   # Create the Shell.Application ComObject
   $Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
   # For each one of the open windows, refresh it.
    $Shell.Windows() | ForEach-Object { $_.Refresh() }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you want to achieve here.

1. Set the value of a registry key which can be done with [`Set-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-7.1).
2. Refresh any open Explorer windows. We can use a ComObject called [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell).[Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-application) to do this.

**N.B.** This will not take effect until you press F5 in an Explorer Window if you do not have any Explorer Windows open.

That being said, you can write a small function much like the one below that will toggle the Hidden Files value in Explorer.

```
function Show-HiddenFiles {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = "On")]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "On")]
        [System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter]
        $On,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = "Off")]
        [System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter]
        $Off
    )
    Process {
        # Set a variable with the value we want to set on the registry value/subkey.
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "On") { $Value = 1 }
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "Off") { $Value = 2 }

        # Define the path to the registry key that contains the registry value/subkey
        $Path = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced"
        # Set the registry value/subkey.
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name Hidden -Value $Value

        # Refresh open Explorer windows.
        # You will need to refresh the window if you have none currently open.
        # Create the Shell.Application ComObject
        $Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
        # For each one of the open windows, refresh it.
        $Shell.Windows() | ForEach-Object { $_.Refresh() }
    }
}
```

Usage is simple.

```
Show-HiddenFiles -On
Show-HiddenFiles -Off
```

---

If you just want to display hidden files in PowerShell you can use either the [-Hidden or -Force parameter of Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1)

`-Hidden` returns only the Hidden files.
`-Force` returns Hidden and non-Hidden files.

Comment: You're welcome, @Evolver. It's not important that it is mine, but you should upvote and accept an answer, IF one has helped you solve your problem. This helps other users find solutions when they have similar questions. Please see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Registry Path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

Name: Hidden

Type: DWord

Settings:

1 = Show

2 = Don't Show

Comment: This, alone, doesn't answer the question because it doesn't tell you what to _do_ with this information in PowerShell.  Your other answer does do that, and I don't think this information needs to be spread out across two answers.