# Uncheck "Show hidden files" in Folder Options with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, registry, microsoft-file-explorer

I'm trying to write a script that turns off Windows Explorer Folder Option "Show hidden files, folders, and drives"

I followed along with this thread:
[Toggle "show hidden files and folders with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67510876/toggle-show-hidden-files-and-folders-with-powershell)

The code in the top answer seems to change the registry key, but the actual Folder Option doesn't change. Hidden files remain visible as well.

Here's my code:

```
$Path = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name Hidden -Value 1

$Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
# For each one of the open windows, refresh it.
$Shell.Windows() | ForEach-Object { $_.Refresh() }
```

I know the registry value is changing because I can check that Hidden is changing with this:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name Hidden
```

Comment: The top-voted answer says "N.B. This will not take effect until you press F5 in an Explorer Window if you do not have any Explorer Windows open."  Have you done that?  Have you tried rebooting, logging off and back on, or otherwise exiting and re-launching Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to restart Explorer.exe to pick up the change.

If you add `stop-process -name explorer –force` to the end of your script does it then pick up the change?

Comment: This worked. I tried doing this using some other code before but the change wasn't picked up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this in PowerShell, but in VBScript I use this solution I developed. The solution works on Windows 10 and 11, and with any language.

**Code:**

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Hidden", 1, "REG_DWORD"

    .RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\Shell\{#}\ExplorerCommandHandler", .RegRead( _
        "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\Shell\Windows.ShowHiddenFiles\ExplorerCommandHandler"), "REG_SZ"

    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(0).ParseName("Shell:RecycleBinFolder").InvokeVerb("{#}")

    .Run("Reg.exe Delete HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\Shell\{#} /F"), 0, True
End With
```